# TypeError when plotting histogram with Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, histogram

I'm trying to plot a histogram of a file of float numbers. The contents of the file look like this:

```
0.1066770707640915
0.0355590235880305
0.0711180471760610
0.4267082830563660
0.0355590235880305
0.1066770707640915
0.0698755355867468
0.0355590235880305
0.0355590235880305
0.0355590235880305
0.0355590235880305
0.0355590235880305
0.2844721887042440
0.0711180471760610
0.0711180471760610
0.0355590235880305
0.0355590235880305
0.1422360943521220
0.0355590235880305
0.0355590235880305
0.0711180471760610
0.0355590235880305
0.0355590235880305
0.0355590235880305
...
```

For some reason, my attempt is throwing me a `TypeError: len() of unsized object`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_file = "inputfile.csv"
file = open(input_file, "r")
all_lines = list(file.readlines())
file.close()

for line in all_lines:
    line = float(line.strip()) # Removing the '\n' at the end and converting to float
    if not isinstance(line, float): # Verifying that all data points could be converted to float
        print type(line)

print len(all_lines)
# 146445

print type(all_lines)
# <type 'list'>

plt.hist(all_lines, bins = 10) # This line throws the error
plt.show()
```

I have scoured SO looking for similar problems. It appears that this error is common when trying to plot non-numeric data types, but this is not the case here, since I explicitly check the data type of each number to ensure that they are not a strange data type.

Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop does not actually convert the items of `all_lines` to floats in place; it just takes each item, converts it to a float and prints it, but it does not change the value in the list. So, when you come to plot `all_lines`, the lines are still stored as strings.

You could instead change all values in the list to floats using a list comprehension as follows:

```
all_lines = [float(line) for line in all_lines]
```

Even better might be to just read the file using `numpy`, and then you will have the lines stored as floats in a numpy array, and save yourself the trouble of iterating through the lines of the file:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

input_file = "inputfile.csv"
all_lines = np.genfromtxt(input_file)

plt.hist(all_lines, bins = 10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a really stupid error to make. For some reason `np.genfromtxt()` didn't work for me, but you did point out the error so I was able to fix it.

Comment: @Antimony: hmm, ok, glad its sorted. So I can clean up the answer, can I ask what the problem was with the `genfromtxt` solution?

Comment: It's unrelated to the question. There were some strange invisible characters at the start of the very first line (which I was processing within the loop, and which is why the list comprehension also did not work), and I believe they tripped up `genfromtxt`.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so the solution stands for the general case of a file structured like the one you have in the question.

Comment: Yeah, the solution probably would work for the general case. I just couldn't test it with my file :)